# Would anybody be able to find the general formula for this pattern?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I have found so far this pattern, and I know it continues on in the same way forever, however I do not know how to write this in proper notation. My n is on the right and when n is 2 or 1 there is no M. And apologies for the terrible handwriting.

[image: This is the pattern that I have so far]

Comment: Sure looks like $M_{n-1} - M_{n-2} + M_{n-3} - M_{n-4} + \cdots$.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you soooo much, I don't know how I didn't see that, but you saved me so much time. Thank you!!! <3

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that the following would work
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} (-1)^{k + n + 1} M_k
$$